# Bayesian Learning with Dynamic Programming

Tags: bayesian, decision-theory

This question is more general than a regular programming question. I am hoping for a reference type of answer.

I am working on a model that involves bayesian learning in a dynamic programming problem. That is, the model has a parameter theta that is uncertain in each period. In each period, there is information which allows the updating of the belief of theta. And in each period, the agents make decisions to maximize a goal. His actions do not affect the signal, i.e not active learning.

The closest model I could find is this http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=982434/. But this paper only does analytical solution, which depends heavily on the assumptions. I would like to know if this type of problems have been systematically studied in math , cs or other disciplines. If yes, can you point me to some references. I would like to be able to simulate model solutions or estimate parameters on a dataset.

Comment: The link no longer works